# Run a profile from command line?

Tags: magento-1.9, importexport, dataflow

I have created an advanced data profile with the below actions xml. It takes a csv of order ids and my adapter marks the orders as complete. When run through the admin panel, this works fine. However, I am wanting to automate the procedure (as the csv will be updated on a semi-regular basis) so have followed the instructions on [Magento Export/Import from the command line](http://phpmysqltalk.com/1718-magento-dataflow-exportimport-form-the-command-line.html) (see below for my code).

When I run this code from the command line I am getting the output "Order status update complete. BatchID: nn", however the orders that I am specifying are not being updated. When I put `var_dump`s and `die`s into my adapter nothing happens. When I do `var_dump`s into the below code I can see that it has loaded the correct profile, and that the actions xml is being read correctly.

How do I get the below code to run my adapter when it is run from the command line?

#### Actions XML

```
<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="load">
    <var name="type">file</var>
    <var name="path">var/import</var>
    <var name="filename"><![CDATA[filename.csv]]></var>
    <var name="format"><![CDATA[csv]]></var>
</action>
<action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="parse">
    <var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[,]]></var>
    <var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>
    <var name="fieldnames">true</var>
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
    <var name="number_of_records">1</var>
    <var name="decimal_separator"><![CDATA[.]]></var>
    <var name="adapter">mynamespace_mymodule/convert_adapter_store</var>
    <var name="method">saveRow</var>
</action>
```

#### Run Profile Code

```
<?php
//THIS SCRIPT JUST INITIALS THE PROFILE TO BE RUN VIA MAGENTO ADMIN "RUN PROFILE IN POPUP".
//Its the same thing as click just via this file that you can run via cron

// SYSTEM - IMPORT/EXPORT - ADVANCED PROFILES <-- you need to go into your magento admin and grab the exact profile ID
$profileId = 9; 

require_once 'public_html/app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$profile = Mage::getModel('dataflow/profile');
$userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$userModel->setUserId(0);
Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->setUser($userModel);
$profile->load($profileId);
if (!$profile->getId()) {
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError('ERROR: Incorrect profile id');
}

Mage::register('current_convert_profile', $profile);
$profile->run();
$batchModel = Mage::getSingleton('dataflow/batch');
echo "ORDER STATUS UPDATE COMPLETE. BATCHID: " . $batchModel->getId();
```

Answer (score 1):

When run from the command line, the `mynamespace_mymodule/convert_adapter_store::saveRow` [method is never called](https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9.2.3/app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php#L126) I'm afraid. Usually, during dataflow imports, the save action is [triggered via the profile popup](https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9.2.3/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Convert/ProfileController.php#L250). That means you need to mimic the controller's `batchRunAction` when executing import profiles from shell. Just append another action to your *Advanced Dataflow Profile XML*:

```
<action type="mynamespace_mymodule/convert_parser_shell" method="save"/>
```

The save method basically contains the code from the controller action, but needs a little tweaking to replace the POST parameters.

```
class MyNamespace_MyModule_Model_Dataflow_Convert_Parser_Shell
    extends Mage_Dataflow_Model_Convert_Adapter_Abstract
{
    public function save()
    {
        $profile = Mage::registry('current_convert_profile');
        $batchId = $profile->getBatchId();

        /** @var Mage_Dataflow_Model_Batch $batchModel */
        $batchModel = Mage::getModel('dataflow/batch')->load($batchId);

        if (!$batchModel->getId()) {
            return;
        }
        if (!$batchModel->getAdapter()) {
            return;
        }

        /** @var Mage_Dataflow_Model_Batch_Import $batchImportModel */
        $batchImportModel = $batchModel->getBatchImportModel();
        $importIds = $batchImportModel->getIdCollection();

        /** @var MyNamespace_MyModule_Model_Convert_Adapter_Store $adapter */
        $adapter = Mage::getModel($batchModel->getAdapter());
        $adapter->setBatchParams($batchModel->getParams());

        // […]
        foreach ($importIds as $importId) {
            // […]
            // THIS actually persists an entity:
            $adapter->saveRow($importData);
            // […]
        }

        // […]
    }

    public function load()
    {
        // not implemented, only import needed.
    }
}
```

I skipped a few lines to focus on the main aspects. See [`batchRunAction`](https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9.2.3/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Convert/ProfileController.php#L214) for reference.

The data juggling depends on the individual entities and adapters anyway.